# Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) in build.gradle.kts when i add rxjava and rxkotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

i can not add rxjava and rxkotlin to build.gradle.kts in intellij-idea and it shows error like this

[image]

what i have to do? i don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `.kts` ( Kotlin script ) file, `implementation` is a kotlin function here, and the dependency should be passed as an argument to it.

```
implementation ("io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.1.5")
implementation ("io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxkotlin:3.0.1")
```